# How to move &copy folder in another folder in Dropbox in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, sdk, dropbox-api

I am working with Dropbox in iPhone SDK. I am able to copy, move load and all other operation with files, But my problem is that how to copy/move a folder into another folder using Dropbox. Is there any way to handle these operations with folders?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the copyFrom and moveFrom functions in DBRestClient to copy and move files or folders, which map to the [/filesops/copy][1] and [/fileops/move][2] calls, respectively.

[1]: https://web.archive.org/web/20130117132813/https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#fileops-move https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#fileops-copy
[2]: https://web.archive.org/web/20130117132813/https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#fileops-move

Comment: can we load folder from dropbox & upload folder onto dropbox?

Comment: The Dropbox API doesn't offer folder or batch uploading or downloading, so you'll want to loop over the desired files to upload/download and use /files_put or /files (GET) accordingly.

Comment: I got solution.Just upload file with upload method & give fullPath name separated by "/" from source  & destination.It will work.